# How to decrease the vertical spacing between formula and text in beamer?

Tags: beamer, spacing

Too much spacing between formula and text in beamer. When I insert the command `\vspace{-0.5cm}` before the formula,  the spacing decreases. But the command `\vspace{-0.5cm}` after the formula has no effect on the spacing between the formula and the text after it.  How to solve it?

Comment: How are you inserting the formula? Use `simple text \begin{equation}\end{equation} followed by text`. Or replace `equation` by other math environments. Don't leave blank lines between the text before and the math. Neither after, unless you want a new paragraph.

Comment: @Sigur My code is :\vspace{-0.5cm}\[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx= f(\xi)(b-a).\]
            \vspace{-0.5cm}  but it dosen't work well.

Comment: I suggest you to use `text above \[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx= f(\xi)(b-a).\] Text after...`

Comment: @Sigur Too much spacing between the formula and text in this case.

Comment: But this is the default. If you want you can reduce space between lines. It is not recommended to insert a lot of negative/positive spaces around blocks. Lets LaTeX decides to you. Later you could have to go back there and change the space if your formula increase/decrease.

Comment: did you try `\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can influence the spacing with `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`. However the default spacing above the equations is already pretty tight, I would not decrease it further.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text above 
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx= f(\xi)(b-a).
\] 
Text after
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt} 
text above 
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx= f(\xi)(b-a).
\]
Text after
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if I should ask a new question, so for now let me try commenting this. Same problem as in the question, solved using this answer. But, even if I define `\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}` globally, it will only affect some equations, but others left as before. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: @Edu Maybe try to change `belowdisplayskip` as well? If this is not helping a new questions including a MWE would be good.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz works for me using `belowdisplayskip`